# Deliver cached page to anonymous user and non-cache to authorized

Tags: django, caching, memcached, django-1.3

I'm using django 1.3 in my app. I need to organize caching, which satisfies following rules:

1. using memcached as cache backend
2. using @cache_page decorator in views, which I want to cache
3. each non-authorized (anonymous) user sees cached version of the page
   (so django should deliver cached version of the page);
4. for each authorized user django should generate new version of page
   (non-cached) and deliver it.

How I can do it? I tried using two decorators below the view:

```
@cache_page(108000)
@vary_on_cookie
```

but when I logged in, first I see the new data, when after updating the data (directly in database by using phpMyAdmin) I refresh the page and see previous content version.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably what you need https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY

Comment: this method has one "-": if I use this option = True, than pages for anonymous users are cached and for authorized users are not cached. but cache generated for anonymous shown for authorized (so, it's not generated for authorized, but shown). I want authorized users always receive actual (not cached) data.

Comment: Are you sure about this? You must remember it is per site caching, done by middleware and you must remove per view caching decorators to work with it.